# Scaling Coordinates after NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics

In order to solve a series of differential equations I had to transfer to the tortoise coordinate defined by

$$x=1-\frac{r_h}{r},$$

but now I have solved them I need to transfer back to the coordinate $r$. My code, after finding the solutions, is given by,

```
Plot[Evaluate[A[x]/.sols],{x,min,max},PlotRange->All]
Plot[Evaluate[B[x]/.sols],{x,min,max},PlotRange->All]
Plot[Evaluate[H[x]/.sols],{x,min,max},PlotRange->All].
```

$x$ runs from $\varepsilon$ to $1-\varepsilon$ and so $r$ runs from $r\approx0$ to $r\rightarrow\infty$ but I only want to go from maybe $r\approx0$ to $r\approx1000r_h$.
Can anyone help me please!

Comment: `f[x] /. x -> 1 - rh/h` or simply `f[1-rh/h]`?  Might rather depend on what the form of `A[x]`, `sols`, `min`, `max` etc. actually are.

Comment: Thanks, it worked great.